# Elegant way to deal with override in C++98,C++11 cross-compilable code?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, overriding

I have some code that has optional built in code that attempts to detect C++0X. Lets pretend that that works (discussing how bad and how not cross platform that is is out of scope for this question). Lets say it has a #define `DETECTCXX0X`. iff it is C++0X.

How awful of an idea is it to do this:

```
#ifndef DETECTCXX0X
#define override
#endif
```

And do you have any alternatives?

(I suppose the correct thing to do is to just not use explicit overriding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik points out it's legal in C++11 and C++98 to say:

```
int override = 10;
```

Because `override` is not really a keyword even in C++11. If your code does this then your macro will mangle it in C++98 mode. If you prohibit using such identifiers and then your method will work fine. The only problem being that you may forget that rule and get hard to understand error messages. If you're using some kind of linter that you can customize then you can add a rule that eliminates this problem.

Another option is Praetorian's solution:

```
#ifndef DETECTCXX0X
#define OVERRIDE
#else
#define OVERRIDE override
#endif
```

This, however, makes for ugly and difficult to read code, IMO.

If you have the luxury to do the following then this is what I recommend:

```
#ifndef DETECTCXX0X
#error C++11 support required
#endif
```

If you can't avoid non-C++11 compilers then a second best option, if you have that linter, is to use it with `#define override`. Third best would be to not use this particular C++11 feature at all. In my view the least desirable option is `#define OVERRIDE override`.

Comment: Indeed. My attempts to make a blank preprocessor 'override' in c++98 were derailed by `class override;`  in `boost::python`

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it slightly differently

```
#ifndef DETECTCXX0X
#define OVERRIDE
#else
#define OVERRIDE override
#endif
```

And then define the function as

```
void foo() OVERRIDE;
```

Doing so avoids flouting the rules. From *§17.6.4.3.1/2 [macro.names]*

> A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically
>   identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the
>   *attribute-tokens* described in 7.6.

*Table 3* includes `override` and `final`. In your case, your macro should be fine too, because in C++03 `override` is not a keyword, so defining a macro does not violate the rule above, and a C++11 compiler will never see that macro definition. But I still prefer the method above.

Comment: When a specific compiler version lacks "override", the corresponding version of Table 3 does not list `override`. Then, for that compiler version, `#define override` does not violate the above-mentioned rule. The rule is violated only for those compilers for which we *don't need* to `#define override`.

Answer (score 1):

That solution seems like a pretty reasonable way to solve the problem you're faced with. It's perfectly fine to `#define` `override` in C++98 because it's not a keyword there.

Comment: ... and so it could be used as an identifier, whereupon the macro will stomp all over it. Note that `override` is not a keyword in C++11 either - it's an "identifier with special meaning".

Comment: @Igor: But as Praetorian's quote indicates, being an identifier rather than a keyword doesn't make redefining it in C++11 ok.