# Is it undefined behavior to #define/#undef an identifier with special meaning?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

An answer to the question [Disable check for override in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30303228/1708801) suggested using `-Doverride=` on the command line to disable errors for erroneous use of [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), which is effectively the same as adding:

```
#define override
```

to the source file.

My initial reaction was that this seems like undefined behavior since we are redefining a keyword but looking at the draft C++11 standard section `2.12` *Keywords [lex.key]* I was surprised that neither *override* nor *final* are keywords. They are covered in the previous section `2.11` *[lex.name]* which says they are identifiers with special meaning:

> The identifiers in Table 3 have a special meaning when appearing in a
>   certain context[...]

and *Table 3* is labelled *Identifiers with special meaning* and includes both *override* and *final*.

The question is, is it undefined behavior to redefine(*using #define*) *identifiers with special meaning*? Are they treated any differently than *keywords* in this respect?

Comment: What is 'redefine'  - a pre-processor macro or a declaration?

Comment: @DieterLücking good catch, I mean using `#define`, edited to clarify.

Comment: @benvoigt these are completely different question

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: **This question already has an answer here** is completely correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22259253/103167

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the C++ standard library it is undefined behavior to redefine *identifiers with special meaning*, this also applies to *keywords*. From the draft C++11 standard under section `17.6.4` *[constraints]* we have section `17.6.4.1` *[constraints.overview]* which says:

> This section describes restrictions on C++ programs that use the
>   facilities of the C++ standard library [...]

and under `17.6.4` we have section `17.6.4.3.1` *[macro.names]* which says:

> A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically
>   identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the
>   attribute-tokens described in 7.6.

*Table 3* list the *Identifiers with special meaning*. We can see this paragraph also covers *keywords* and they are treated in the same manner.

Comment: Asked and answered in the same minute by the same person - mmm.

Comment: @DieterLücking please see [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/213111)

Comment: Doing that, you should have a well defined title and question.

Comment: Before posting a fabricated Q&A, you should first check that you are not duplicating existing information.

Comment: @BenVoigt I always research, I have asked several well received questions, so I feel I have a good understanding of what a duplicate is and I believe calling this a duplicate is a stretch. I don't really have the time to make a post to meta but I will when I do have the time properly respond to comments etc... This was an honest attempt to share what I discovered when I ran into a question I did not believe was asked before.

Answer (score 1):

Implementations' standard header files are allowed to "implement" standard functions using macros in cases where a macro could meet the requirements for the function (including ensuring that arguments are evaluated exactly once).  Further, such macros are allowed to make use of keywords or identifiers whose behavior is specified in in the standard or "reserved to the implementation"; use of such macros in contexts where the keywords or identifiers have been redefined could have arbitrary effects.

That having been said, the historical interpretation of this form of UB would be to say that compilers shouldn't go out of their way to cause wacky behavior, and outside of "pedantic modes" should allow user code to assign meanings to reserved identifiers the compiler would otherwise not use. This can be helpful in cases where code should be usable both on compilers which would require a keyword like `__packed`, and on compilers which neither recognize nor require such a keyword.). Redefining keywords in the fashion you're doing is a bit dodgier; it will probably work, but there's a significant likelihood that that it will disrupt the behavior of a standard-library macro.

Comment: `...allowed to "implement" standard functions using macros` -- Really? Do they need to support taking the address of a function so "implemented"?

Comment: Wouldn't defining a function as a macro create different scoping rules?  Ex: if printf() was a macro, then I couldn't have a local variable named printf.

Comment: @MobyDisk: Is it legal for to have a local variable named `printf` within a complation unit that includes `<stdio.h>`?  I thought that was Undefined Behavior (though in practice it will usually either shadow the external printf function as though the outside name didn't exist or will yield compilation errors, rather than warping the fabric of time and causality).

Comment: That is definitely legal since they are different scopes.

Comment: @MobyDisk: For normal user-defined functions, that would be true, but I don't think the standard requires that compilers allow any symbol defined in a standard header to be used for *any* other purpose.  A typical `stdio.h`, for example, includes `#define getchar() getc(stdin)`, and from what I can tell that has always been a perfectly standards-compliant implementation. BTW, I don't think that would cause any conflict with local variables *except* when the variable was a function pointer type and code tried to invoke it as `getchar()` rather than `(getchar)()`.

Comment: Neither gcc nor Microsoft Visual Studio define getchar() as a macro.  Doing so would expand a local variable like "int getchar" to be "int getc(stdin)" which would be a compile error.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e1b0f76e0c04e7

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you did there.  #define getchar() WITH THE PARENS.  TRICKY!!!  I never imagined that was legal...

Comment: The C standard (C99 7.1.4) says that "any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header".  Note that you can still take the address of such a function name, because there won't be the following parens that trigger macro-replacement. As far as I know, C++ doesn't have the same phrase - I suppose it at least inherits it for the C headers; I'm not sure if it extends the same restriction to names in C++ headers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That practice is disallowed by [headers]/p6: "Names that are defined as functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ standard library. [Footnote: This disallows the practice, allowed in C, of providing a masking macro in addition to the function prototype. The only
way to achieve equivalent inline behavior in C++ is to provide a definition as an extern inline function.] "

Comment: @T.C.: thanks for the pointer. So C++ not only disallows it for C++ headers, it 'retroactively' disallows it for C headers.